# Do queries from subqueried tables get optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

About query optimizations, I'm wondering if statements like one below get optimized:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 using (entity_id)
    order by t2.sort_order, t1.name
)   as foo -- main query of object
where foo.name = ?; -- inserted
```

Consider that the query is taken care by a dependency object but just (rightly?) allows one to tack in a WHERE condition. I'm thinking that at least not a lot of data gets pulled in to your favorite language, but I'm having second thoughts if that's an adequate optimization and maybe the database is still taking some time going through the query.

Or is it better to take that query out and write a separate query method that has the where and maybe a `LIMIT 1` clause, too?

Comment: Please do *not* post questions that are quite DBMS-specific like this as general cross-DBMS questions. If it isn't DBMS-specific just use the `SQL` tag. If it is DBMS specific, *pick one tag* and use that. Which answer can you mark as "correct" here, when there's one for MySQL and one for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @CraigRinger: You should just vote to close as 'Too Broad'

Comment: @Flimzy: vote to close as 'Too Broad'... **after removing the tag that specified `mysql`**.

Comment: @spencer7593: The question had two, conflicting tags: mysql *and* postgresql.

Comment: @Flimzy: then removing **one** of the tags is sufficient to resolve the conflict. It's not necessary to remove **both** of them.

Comment: @Flimzy: While it's best to concentrate on a specific RDBMS for such a question, it would be wrong to change tags *after* useful answers for both MySQL *and* Postgres have been given. I restored both tags. Leave them.

Comment: sorry if i caused a little contention here. i'm actually fond and actively using both dbms for quite some time and really interested on knowing how both handle scenarios like that. my sorry again. i'll go punch myself now.

Comment: @Agi: You ought to ask two questions then, one for each RDBMS.

Comment: @Flimzy: Yes, I realized that only too late. I also wasn't aware that you can only tag one as the best answer. Sorry, will keep this in mind. And thanks to everyone who answered, it was very enlightening.

Comment: @Agi: There are times when both tags can be appropriate... such as when asking how to to do X in postgres in mysql, or vice versa. The general rule is, there should be one, specific answer per question. Your question solicits two answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I can't speak for MySQL - not to mention the fact that it probably varies by storage engine and MySQL version, but for PostgreSQL:*

PostgreSQL will flatten this into a single query. The inner `ORDER BY` isn't a problem, because adding or removing a predicate cannot affect the ordering of the remaining rows.

It'll get flattened to:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 using (entity_id)
where foo.name = ?
order by t2.sort_order, t1.name;
```

then the join predicate will get internally converted, producing a plan corresponding to the SQL:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, ..., t2.col1, t2.col2, ...
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where 
   t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
   and foo.name = ?
order by t2.sort_order, t1.name;
```

Example with a simplified schema:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE demo1 (id integer primary key, whatever integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
regress=> INSERT INTO demo1 (id, whatever) SELECT x, x FROM generate_series(1,100) x;
INSERT 0 100
regress=> EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM demo1
    ORDER BY id
) derived
WHERE whatever % 10 = 0;
                        QUERY PLAN                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=2.51..2.51 rows=1 width=8)
   Sort Key: demo1.id
   ->  Seq Scan on demo1  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1 width=8)
         Filter: ((whatever % 10) = 0)
 Planning time: 0.173 ms
(5 rows)
```

... which is the same plan as:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM demo1
WHERE whatever % 10 = 0
ORDER BY id;
                        QUERY PLAN                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=2.51..2.51 rows=1 width=8)
   Sort Key: id
   ->  Seq Scan on demo1  (cost=0.00..2.50 rows=1 width=8)
         Filter: ((whatever % 10) = 0)
 Planning time: 0.159 ms
(5 rows)
```

If there was a `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, a window function, or certain other things that prevent qualifier push-down/pull-up/flattening in the inner query then PostgreSQL would recognise that it can't safely flatten it. It'd evaluate the inner query either by materializing it or by iterating over its output and feeding that to the outer query.

The same applies for a view. PostgreSQL will in-line and flatten views into the containing query where it is safe to do so.

Comment: +1. Very nice explanation. (I have very little experience with Postgres, and that was quite a few years back, but very nicely explained.)

Answer (score 5):

In **MySQL**, no.

The predicate in an outer query does *not* get "pushed" down into the inline view query.

The query in the inline view is processed first, independent of the outer query. (MySQL will optimize that view query just like it would optimize that query if you submitted that separately.)

The way that MySQL processes this query: the inline view query gets run first, the result is materialized as a 'derived table'. That is, the result set from that query gets stored as a temporary table, in memory in some cases (if it's small enough, and doesn't contain any columns that aren't supported by the MEMORY engine. Otherwise, it's spun out to disk with as a MyISAM table, using the MyISAM storage engine.

Once the derived table is populated, then the outer query runs.

(Note that the derived table does *not* have any indexes on it. That's true in MySQL versions before 5.6; I think there are some improvements in 5.6 where MySQL will actually create an index.

**Clarification: indexes on derived tables:** As of MySQL 5.6.3 "During query execution, the optimizer may add an index to a derived table to speed up row retrieval from it." Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Also, I don't think MySQL "optimizes out" any unneeded columns from the inline view. If the inline view query is a `SELECT *`, then all of the columns will be represented in the derived table, whether those are referenced in the outer query or not.

This can lead to some significant performance issues, especially when we don't understand how MySQL processes a statement. (And the way that MySQL processes a statement is significantly *different* from other relational databases, like Oracle and SQL Server.)

You may have heard a recommendation to "avoid using views in MySQL". The reasoning behind this general advice (which applies to both "stored" views and "inline" views) is the significant performance issues that can be unnecessarily introduced.

As an example, for this query:

```
SELECT q.name
  FROM ( SELECT h.*
           FROM huge_table h
       ) q
 WHERE q.id = 42
```

MySQL does not "push" the predicate `id=42` down into the view definition. MySQL first runs the inline view query, and essentially creates a copy of `huge_table`, as an un-indexed MyISAM table. Once that is done, then the outer query will scan the copy of the table, to locate the rows satisfying the predicate.

If we instead re-write the query to "push" the predicate into the view definition, like this:

```
SELECT q.name
  FROM ( SELECT h.*
           FROM huge_table h
          WHERE h.id = 42
       ) q
```

We expect a much smaller resultset to be returned from the view query, and the derived table should be much smaller. MySQL will also be able to make effective use of an index `ON huge_table (id)`. But there's still some overhead associated with materializing the derived table.

If we eliminate the unnecessary columns from the view definition, that can be more efficient (especially if there are a lot of columns, there are any large columns, or any columns with datatypes not supported by the MEMORY engine):

```
SELECT q.name
  FROM ( SELECT h.name
           FROM huge_table h
          WHERE h.id = 42
       ) q
```

And it would be even more efficient to eliminate the inline view entirely:

```
SELECT q.name
  FROM huge_table q
 WHERE q.id
```

Comment: Wow, really? There's no qualifier pull-up/push-down in MySQL?

Comment: "MySQL will actually create an index". I seriously doubt that MySQL automatically creates indexes on the fly for materialized tables during query execution.

Comment: CraigRinger: That's correct. In MySQL, predicates are not pushed into view queries, which is *much* different than the behavior we've come to expect in other database engines. @ErwinBrandstetter: I thought I had seen somewhere that MySQL had added or was adding (in version 5.6, 5.7? or maybe it was MariaDB?) a feature to automatically create indexes on derived table when the optimizer detected that it would improve performance. (I don't have that reference available at the moment.) I am sure that **no** indexes are created for derived tables in version 5.5 and earlier.

Comment: @spencer7593: If you should stumble across a reference for that, that would certainly be interesting.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: It's in the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html) **8.2.1.18.3** As of MySQL 5.6.3... "During query execution, the optimizer may add an index to a derived table to speed up row retrieval from it."

Comment: @spencer7593: Well deserved upvote. The deep link actually answers much of this question: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html#from-clause-subquery-optimization

Comment: @spencer7593 Cool feature. We've discussed doing that for materialized subqueries / CTEs in PostgreSQL but nobody's got around to it yet.

Comment: @spencer7593 : so how do experienced MySQL users get around this limitation? Coming from Oracle, this looks like a huge downside for MySQL. But given how popular it is, I have a hard time believing there is no way around this...

Comment: @static_rtti:  way around what?  If we want a predicate in an inline view, then we add a predicate in the inline view. If we should have a predicate there, and we don't, we can suffer a performance penalty. We know the MySQL optimizer differs from the Oracle optimizer. We evaluate performance against production size (non-trivial) sets, use EXPLAIN to see the query execution plans, ...

Comment: @spencer7593 my question is, how do you reuse views if the optimizer can't push predicates into them? Can you make parameterized views? Can you manually inject the predicate?

Comment: This answer was given in 2014, regarding handling of derived tables (inline views)  in MySQL 5.6.  (i.e. before MySQL 5.7 was released in 2015). Compare the documentation for MySQL 5.6 here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-table-optimization.html and MySQL 8.0 here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html ... also see the ALGORITHM=MERGE for stored views.